# Google Maps API - PHP/MySQL/Ajax

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As per this page
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#createmap

I have created a successfull map pulling data of around 200 users from MySQL and mapping them...however not all markers show.

I understand that there is a page for 'Too Many Markers' or something, but I don't seem to be getting any errors - just not all of them show (only around 25-30). If I refresh the page, some remain, some disappear, swapped with other markers from other users.

I understand this is probably some loading issue, can anyone give me any tips of how I can use the existing code as displayed on the website (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#createmap) to slow down the request so all markers show each time?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is `phpsqlajax_genxml.php` generating XML with all 200 users??

Comment: Hello @davidstrachan - Yes, the XML is returning all results, although this isn't reflected on the map markers for some reason.

Comment: What does that XML look like?  Does it include the coordinates or just addresses?